# Change popup window to include HTML

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow, liquid

I have a popup window triggered by Ajax upon form submission. Currently it works fine, but I want to edit the code so that it will show HTML content (instead of "Added to cart, thank you!", the content it's clearly already pulling, I want to show the updated cart and give people the option to continue shopping and check out.)

I just don't know how to change the code to stop pulling just the text out of the div. Any ideas?

```
//Added, show message & update cart display

window.showQuickPopup("Added to cart, thank you!", $form.find('input[type="submit"]:first'));
$.get(shopifyAjaxStorePageURL, function(data){
     var $newCartObj = $(data).find('#navpanel .cartsummary');
     var $currCart = $('#navpanel .cartsummary');
     if($currCart.length == 0) {
        $('#shoplogo').after($newCartObj);
     } else {
        $currCart.html($newCartObj.html());

     //Function to show a quick generic text popup above an element

     window.showQuickPopup = function(message, $origin){
     var $popup = $('<div>').addClass ('simple-popup');
     var offs = $origin.offset();
     $popup.html(message).css({ 'left':offs.left, 'top':offs.top }).hide();
     $('body').append($popup);
     $popup.css('margin-top', - $popup.outerHeight() - 10);
     $popup.fadeIn(200).delay(3500).fadeOut(400, function(){
         $(this).remove();
     });
};
```

Comment: You should provide the most of HTML, JavaScript code, and the file that is requested by Ajax.

Comment: Or, which will be better a lot -- generalize, concretize and clarify your question. I can't get in your problem at all.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that where you have `"Added to cart, thank you!"` ...

```
window.showQuickPopup("Added to cart, thank you!", $form.find('input[type="submit"]:first'));
```

you can use html instead.

So for example

```
var myHtmlVersion = '<div class="popup-block">Added to cart, thank you!</div>
window.showQuickPopup(myHtmlVersion, $form.find('input[type="submit"]:first'));
```

Of course the html can be as comprehensive as you like.